# Jenkins Tool vs Slave local tool

Tags: jenkins, gradle

What is the difference between using maven as a tool versus having a slave that has maven installed?

I am using Jenkins on OCP and it came with a slave image for maven and not setup as a tool. I now need to install gradle and I am wondering if I should add it as a tool or make a slave with it installed.

Answer (score 1):

Installing it as a tool allows Jenkins to manage the binary and ensure it's available for your build while also providing supporting pipeline syntax `withEnv()`. Having an agent with the binary allows you to shell out and run your commands using `sh` without `withEnv()`. It also allows you to decide where these binaries come from depending on your agent type (*static, vm, container, pod*).

Personally, I prefer the latter because I can control the updating of said binaries on the agent in a more automated fashion.